# How to append a element in list forever?

Tags: list, save

How can i append an element to the list forever?It means if next time i open my file,the element i append still exist.Please help me thanks!

```
    book_list=["good","best"]
    new_book=input("Enter new book name")
    book_list.append(new_book)
    print(book_list)
```

Answer (score 0):

Every time press one is triggered you init the book_list with empty list, and when user press two you also reinit the list overwriting the previous state. You should do this init before the loop that you have this conditions in.

You are basically creating new empty list ever time an action is triggered and you cannot do that if you want to see your updates.

By the init/clear i mean this line:

```
book_list = []
```

So it should look similar to this:

```py
    book_list = []
    while True:
        action = input("Chose 1 for... 2 for...")
        if action == "1":
             print(book_list)
        elif action == "2":
             new_book = input("Enter new book name")
             book_list.append(new_book)
```

Comment: Can you tell me how to solve it?I am confused to use which functions to keep the list updated.Thanks for your anwsering!

Comment: I assume that you have some kind of a loop in which you check what is first user input and then based on this condition chose action. I will not write everything for you but the part with using list. (I will edit)

Comment: It would be also good idea to validate the input or add a default (else) case, and adjust print info.